# javascript - find the composition of data types in array w/o a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to find the data type composition of an array without using a loop like below

```
var anArray = [
        52,
        "A string",
        new Date(),
        "spatula"
    ],
    typeVar,
    compOfArray = {};

for (var i in anArray) {
    typeVar = typeof anArray[i];
    if (!compOfArray[typeVar])   compOfArray[typeVar] = true;
    else                         compOfArray[typeVar] += 1;
}
```

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do that without a loop. Btw, a `for..in` loop is [the wrong way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/5743988) to iterate over an array.

Comment: `compOfArray = anArray.reduce((obj,val)=> (obj[t=typeof val] = (obj[t]|0)+1, obj), {})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `reduce`-function to build up an object which keeps track of how many of each types are in the array:

```
var compOfArray = anArray.reduce(function(a,b){
  typeof b in a ? a[typeof b]++ : a[typeof b] = 1;
  return a
},{});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can check any array methods by using `Array.prototype in the console` or check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)